# Powershell string.split

Tags: powershell, split

```
$version = Get-EventLog 
               -Newest 1 
               -ComputerName $systemnummer 'Symantec Endpoint Protection Client' 
               -Message "*Version*" | Select message 
[string]$version = $version
$version = $version.Split(":")
```

After getting the Eventlog Entry $version contains the following string:
`"@{Message=New virus definition file loaded. Version: 150317001.}"`

How can i split the String to get only the number "150317001"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your message string is still a property (Message) of the object, so you need to reference it by that property name:

```
$version = Get-EventLog 
               -Newest 1 
               -ComputerName $systemnummer 'Symantec Endpoint Protection Client' 
               -Message "*Version*" | Select message 
$version = $version.Message.Split(":")[1]
```

Or use `Select -ExpandProperty` to get just the value:

```
$version = Get-EventLog 
               -Newest 1 
               -ComputerName $systemnummer 'Symantec Endpoint Protection Client' 
               -Message "*Version*" | Select -ExpandProperty message 
$version = $version.Split(":")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$version = Get-EventLog -Newest 1 -ComputerName $systemnummer 'Symantec Endpoint Protection Client' -Message "*Version*" | Select message 
$ver = $version.message -replace ".*(\d+).*", "`$1"
```

Comment: i tried, but im sorry... your $ver seems to be empty

Comment: Don't cast to `[string]` before doing the code I added, just leave `$version` as it is when returned from `Get-Eventlog`

Comment: Consider using  `Select -expand message` to just get the string back. Remove one hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

Just use regex for this. Here code for your example:

```
$content = '@{Message=New virus definition file loaded. Version: 150317001.}';
$regex = 'version\s*:\s*(\d+)';
$resultingMatches = [Regex]::Matches($content, $regex, "IgnoreCase")
$version = $resultingMatches[0].Groups[1].Value
```